# Type conversion in Perl

Tags: perl, types, type-conversion

I am trying to learn Perl [here](http://learnperl.scratchcomputing.com/tutorials/csss/) and the tutorial suggests the following code snippet after reading some file:

```
my $team_number = 42;
my $filename = 'input.txt';

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "cannot open '$filename' $!";

my $found;
while(<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  last if($_ eq "Team $team_number");
}
die "cannot find 'Team $team_number'" if(eof $fh);
```

Why don't you need quotes around `42` when you are clearly comparing an integer to a string? Is Perl smart enough to do such type converting itself?

Comment: Yes: [*Legal type conversions — for example, conversions from number to string — are done automatically at run time; illegal type conversions are fatal errors.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Features)

Comment: A note: that ressource is a little bit outdated, but seems to be still fine. Due to Perl's long history, there is a lot of very old, bad stuff around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Perl is [a *strongly typed* language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), it does not have static types. The concept of distinct *integers*, *strings* or *floats* is not there in Perl.

Instead, when speaking about *types*, it refers to these three:

- scalars
- arrays
- hashes

They are explained in the [perldoc *perldata*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

> Perl has three built-in data types: scalars, arrays of scalars, and associative arrays of scalars, known as "hashes". A scalar is a single string (of any size, limited only by the available memory), number, or a reference to something (which will be discussed in perlref). Normal arrays are ordered lists of scalars indexed by number, starting with 0. Hashes are unordered collections of scalar values indexed by their associated string key.

Both numbers and strings are *scalars*, which means that they are one single value.

There are, however, operators for numerical and string comparison, like `==` and `eq`. They are useful for example when sorting.

Comment: Would one then use `eq` or `==` when the 'type' of two variables to compare are not known in advance?

Comment: @Bram usually you would use `eq`, because `==` will give you a _warning_ `Argument "a" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)` if you do `'a' == 1`. The code will continue running though.

Comment: Also `0.0 == 0` but not `"0.0" eq "0"`

Comment: Perl has way more than three data types. It even has more than three variables types (`$foo`, `@foo`, `%foo`, `*foo`, `&foo`).

Comment: @ikegami the documentation says otherwise; the five different sigils you've mentioned all point to the same symbol in the symbol table, and `&foo` is not a variable, it's a subroutine. If you reference it, you'll get a code-ref, which is a ref, which is a scalar.

Comment: The documentation quite easily demonstrably wrong (`"a"|"b"` vs `1|2`). You're limited with what you can do with `&foo`, but it is a variable (`\&foo`), and it is a variable type (`CV`).

Comment: @ikegami In that case, feel free to fix it: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhack.html :)

Answer (score 3):

Perl is smart enough to do such type conversion itself.

- An operator that requires a string coerces its operand into a string.
- An operator that requires an integer coerces its operand into an integer.
- An operator that requires a number coerces its operand into an integer or float.
- etc

The literal `42` results in an integer value. But string concatenation<sup>[1]</sup> requires strings for operands, so it coerces it into a string.

---

1. `"Team $team_number"` is identical to `"Team " . $team_number`.